# randomchoicest() is giving attribute error

Tags: python

This is my python script:

```
import random
n=random.randint(1,100)
print(n)
```

This is the error I am getting while running the above script in linux mint terrminal:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ran1.py", line 2, in <module>
    n=random.randint(1,100)
AttributeError: module 'random' has no attribute 'randint'
```

Also other attributes in random module like `random.choice()`, `random.choices()` give the same error.

Kindly help me out anyone.

Comment: Have you by any chance created a file called `random.py` ?

Comment: make sure that random module is being imported correctly. Try including this line as second line of your script `print(random)` and make sure the random module from python libraries is being loaded.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a file named random.py that you made, you may want to open it and look for the randint and choice functions in it, or the python is not installed correctly.

Comment: Add `from random import *` to the top of that file, or rename it.